# Can't make my layout Scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll

I want to make scrollable layout becuase my TextView has long text. I searched and found some solution, like create a ScrollView inside my RelativeLayout and create another RelativeLayout inside there. and changed my xml code like this. but nothing happened.

this is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.arsh.fina.IntroActivity">

<include layout="@layout/content"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/surv1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A VERY 
        VERY 
        VERy  
        VERY TEXT"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    android:id="@+id/a1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp">


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/a2"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

where do I go wrong?

Comment: what actually happens when this is on the device?

Comment: @DroiDev nothing happened. emulator shows me this activity. I think i saw the scroll bar when activity start for 1 or 2 second, but i cant scroll. what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on the device. The reason it probably doesnt scroll on your end is because there is nothing to scroll using the code you provided us. meaning you textivew isnt long enough

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vzw.www.deviceid.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="#cdcdcd"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A VERY
        VERY
        dfsdfdsf
        sdf
        dsfsdfsd
        fds
        fsdfsdf
        sdf
        sdf
        sd
        fsd
        f
        sdf
        sdf
        sdf
        sdf
        sd
        fsd
        f
        sd
        fsd
        fds
        fs
        df
        sd
        fsd
        fsd
        f
        sd
        fsd
        f
        sdf
        sd
        f
        VERy
        VERY TEXT"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: really really thanks for your time. my text view has long enough and i type "VERY VERY VERY TEXT" to summarize it.
i gave an idea from your answer, i change location of my scrollview and my drawer navigation, and it work correctly!!!! :| 
thanks for your time again

Comment: great. glad my answer helped.